# Jest can't find several files in the __tests__ folder

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to use jest with vue.js framework. When I run yarn test:unit (eg. vue-cli-service test:unit) the only recognized file in the tests folder is the last, however I have several files.
I don't understand why. I tried to add the path of the folder **tests**, of the other files, without success
Could you help me please ?

I used vue add unit-jest in an existing project.

Here the structure of my project :

```
> __tests__
  example.test.js
  example1.test.js
  example2.test.js
  example3.test.js
  example4.test.js
> src

 // jest.config.js
 module.exports = {
      verbose: true,
      preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest',
      testMatch: [
        '<rootDir>/**/*.(test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
        '<rootDir>/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
      ],
      transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!vuetify|vue-select)'],
      setupFiles: ['./utils/setup.js'],

//.eslintrc
      "env": {
        "jest": true
      }

// package.json
   "scripts": {
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit --watch=all --coverage",
    }
```

versions :
"@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.3",
"@vue/vue2-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.2",
"babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
"jest": "^27.0.5",
"@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0",

output :

```
  PASS  __tests__/example4.test.js (6.415 s)
  App.vue
    √ should return true (12 ms)
...
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.217 s
Ran all test suites.
Done in 10.71s.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but can you try to replace the `testMatch` on `config.jest.js` to something like this?

```js
testMatch: [
  '<rootDir>/**/*.test.js',
],
```

Comment: Hi, this regex has no effect